# Deleting all the data using time less than 9am in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, datepart

I am trying to delete all rows from a Postgres database that occur before 8:58am everyday without removing any dates that come before.

I have tried using SELECT * from  where DATEPART(hh, request_time) < 09, which works when using Microsoft SQL Server on a different database, but when I run this same script against PostgreSQL I am getting an error on the "hh" as it says this column does not exist.

This is what I get when I select the data on the other database. I would like this to be deleted in the end without affecting the day before
SQL server: `SELECT * from <table> where DATEPART(hh, request_time) < 09`

```
2019-04-26 08:59:26.000
2019-04-27 03:01:25.000
2019-04-29 02:06:46.000
```

MobaXterm:

```sql
 SELECT * from <table> where DATEPART(hh, start_time) < 09;
```

```
 error message: column "hh" does not exist
```

I expect any rows that are before 9am in the database table to be deleted, therefore I will only have results that are after 9 am in the database in the end.
edit: This is now working for hour, however, I wish to make it that anything before 8:58 will be deleted. I currently have "select * from table where start_time::time < '05:45:01';" which is working, apart from including a few extra rows that come after the time such as: 2019-02-27 05:46:15.152079

Comment: Is the "actual database" also Microsoft SQL Server? What does `SELECT @@VERSION;` return?

Comment: The database is PostgreSQL and I am getting the error: "column "version" does not exist"

Comment: Added the `postgresql` tag to your question. That was a rather important detail not included in your question.

Comment: @kwood . . . Postgres is *not* SQL Server.  You need to tag your questions correctly.

Comment: There is no `datepart()` in Postgres, only [`date_part()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: Is there any reason that when I write: select * from table where start_time::time < '07:57:01.000000'; that I am getting results after this time? It seems to be listening to it until a couple of minutes after this time. Examples being: "2019-02-27 07:58:41.173908" "2019-03-21 08:01:26.324988"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres is *not* SQL Server.  You can use `extract()`:

```
select *
from <table>
where extract(hour from start_time) < 9;
```

More generally, you can use:

```
where start_time::time < '9:00:00'
```

Comment: That's it, thank you Gordon. Would it be possible to add in a minute value as well? Say I wanted <8:58 to be deleted? Apologies forgot to include that it was Postgres

Comment: Thank you for providing the general use for start time. When I run this I am getting some rows that are after the time stated: select * from <table> where start_time::time < '05:45'; rows returning : 2019-02-27 05:44:45.150773 | 2019-02-27 05:46:15.152635

Answer (score 0):

it would be `hour` instead `hh`

```
SELECT * from table_name where DATEPART(hour, start_time) < 09
```

Comment: I have just tried SELECT * from <table> where DATEPART(hour, start_time) < 09;
and I am getting the same error of "column "hour" does not exist"

Comment: @kwood https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=51222e99a5d55b29a89b21116afd970a i share with you example of that function

Comment: It should be date_part('hour', start_time)